# Unwanted Line breaks in Bibliography

Tags: natbib

I'm using `natbib` to manage my bibliography, but it keeps breaking the line, rather than using the whole width of the page.

I would like it like so:

Acemoglu (2002) Directed technical change *Journal*

instead of like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openbib]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{newapa}

\begin{document}
\cite{Acemoglu2002}
\bibliography{lit}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE: see <http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography/4408#4408>

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `openbib` option.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{newapa}

\begin{document}
\cite{doody}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]